# Localstack - Can't access dashboard

Tags: localstack

I'm using localstack to simulate SNS and SQS but every time I try to use the dashboard I keep getting this error:

```
    2019-08-19T09:59:58:WARNING:localstack.dashboard.infra: Error running command: { test `which aws` || . .venv/bin/activate; }; aws --endpoint-url="http://localhost:4576" sqs list-queues [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/cache.b40b5dc1d0a8d40f3b34502cd285c718.json
```

I'm running localstack with the docker flag because I don't think I can get the dashboard without docker.

Comment: You can view your data in LocalStack directly from Commandeer  https://getcommandeer.com/blog/install-localstack . Not sure why the dashboard doesn't show though.

Comment: The link for the dashboard is https://dashboard.localstack.localdev/ for anyone coming in from google

Answer (score 20):

A little deep in the README.md for the github localstack it says:

```
PORT_WEB_UI: Port for the Web user interface / dashboard (default: 8080). 
Note that the Web UI is now deprecated, 
and requires to use the localstack/localstack-full Docker image.
```

Try using the `localstack/localstack-full` image instead.

Comment: @corbor11, I used that image, but it I keep getting a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in the port 8080

Comment: @CristianoAraujo - make sure have the port binding set

Comment: @CristianoAraujo I have added port binding for the UI but still not able to see. I can see the UI with localstack: 0.10.7 but not with the localstack-full image.
ports:
      - "4567-4599:4567-4599"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
This is what you mean right?
along with ENV variable
- PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }

Answer (score 9):

For those still running into this question, do note that the **latest** `localstack/localstack-full` image is no longer a fallback for the dashboard, as [the interface itself has been fully removed from that image](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/4535#issuecomment-912360013) as well.

The only way to retain the dashboard is using a previous version of the same image, such as `localstack:localstack-full:0.11.6` which is the latest version that still contains the dashboard (v0.12.x onwards won't have it).

The caveat being, obviously, since this is an older image, several updated dependencies you have may break in an untraceable manner when interacting with localstack.

Once set up, a successful(-ish) build of that image renders the below layout at `http://localhost:8080/#!/infra`:
[image]